# How do I echo a payload of JSON data sent via POST method in my browser?

Tags: php, json, post, webhooks

I am trying to visually see the JSON data that gets sent from a webcam site in order to verify that it is being received. I built a php handler and pointed the webhook at it, yet it is not showing up in the browser or in the network traffic. Here is the JSON data:

```
Body 
payload={
"version":"1.0",
"event":"video_recorded",
"data":{
"videoName":"randomstringofstuff",
"audioCodec":"NellyMoser ASAO",
"videoCodec":"H.264",
"type":"FLV",
"orientation":"landscape",
"id":"278264",
"dateTime":"2017-04-04 23:06:29",
"timeZone":"America/Los_Angeles",
"payload":"",
"httpReferer":"http://www.whateversite.is/mytest/"
}}
```

From the site where I input the URL for my php script it says I can retrieve the data with:

```
$data = $_POST["payload"];
$retrievedData = json_decode($data, true);
```

I tried to echo the $retrievedData Variable:

```
echo $retrievedData;
```

However, when I do so and try sending another test payload and refreshing the page I don't have anything on the page. I have also tried:

```
print_r['$_POST'];
```

which just returns:

```
Array ()
```

From the site where I initiate the POST it returns that it went through successful, and according to the help desk the POST won't appear in the network traffic due to it being sent from a server, not their site. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `echo $_POST["payload"];`

Comment: I have also tried this, there is still nothing showing up.